# MySQL Triggers Liquibase

Tags: mysql, triggers, liquibase

I have liquibase set up. I currently have 4-5 triggers I would like to load, with each trigger stored in a separate file. All of the triggers are on separate tables. However I keep getting this error:

> SEVERE 9/17/13 12:05 PM:liquibase: Change Set migrations/09-16-2013-16-10.sql::129  failed.  Error: Error executing SQL DELIMITER $$

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `UPDATE_tableA` BEFORE UPDATE on `tableA`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF (OLD.ColumnA = NEW.ColumnA) and 
  ((OLD.ColumnB is null and NEW.ColumnB is null) or (OLD.ColumnB = NEW.ColumnB)) and 
  ((OLD.ColumnB is null and NEW.ColumnB is null) or (OLD.ColumnB = NEW.ColumnB)) and 
  ((OLD.ColumnC is null and NEW.ColumnC is null) or (OLD.ColumnC = NEW.ColumnC))  
  THEN
    SET NEW.ColumnA = 0;
    SET NEW.ColumnB = NULL;
    SET NEW.ColumnB = NULL;
    SET NEW.ColumnC = NULL;
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `UPDATE_tableB` BEFORE UPDATE on `tableB`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF (OLD.ColumnA = NEW.ColumnA) and 
  ((OLD.ColumnB is null and NEW.ColumnB is null) or (OLD.ColumnB = NEW.ColumnB)) and 
  ((OLD.ColumnB is null and NEW.ColumnB is null) or (OLD.ColumnB = NEW.ColumnB)) and 
  ((OLD.ColumnC is null and NEW.ColumnC is null) or (OLD.ColumnC = NEW.ColumnC))  
  THEN
    SET NEW.ColumnA = 0;
    SET NEW.ColumnB = NULL;
    SET NEW.ColumnB = NULL;
    SET NEW.ColumnC = NULL;
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: one of those ColumnB's should be considered a ColumnD ie. I'm not trying to set the value of one column twice.

Comment: Did you put the sql for the trigger in a formatted sql file or in an xml changeset file?

Comment: If you are using formatted sql for this maybe the problem in [this forum post](http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/enddelimiter-in-formatted-sql-changelogs) does apply to you...

Comment: I managed to find a work around by using gradle plugin. I've added details here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62654020/using-liquibase-to-create-triggers-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

'endDelimiter' is a regExp so try this instead

```
<sqlFile endDelimiter="\$\$" path="..."/>
```

Answer (score 0):

DELIMITER `$$` is a command understood by the MySQL client parser, but not through JDBC that Liquibase uses.

You need to specify the delimiter in how you reference the file, perhaps as `<sqlFile endDelimiter="$$" path="..."/>`